# c# send specific data in TcpClient class

Tags: c#, mobile, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a TCP server software and accepting a client by

```
TcpClient NewClient = TCPListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

line. Also i have a string list that holds safe client IP's. If an unknown client wants to enter the system, i reject it by

```
NewClient.Close();
```

line. This is not problem for static IP devices. Problem starts for mobile devices. A mobile device may have different IP's for each connection so i should check its imei number as soon as possible when i accept it. Is there any field that i can immidiately reach to check imei number? I also design mobile software so while i am connecting to server, i want to pass the imei number of phone by TcpClient class.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any field that i can immidiately reach to check imei number?

No. IMEI is not a concept which is part of TCP/IP at all. If you need to know the IMEI number, you'll need some other way of getting it. You haven't said anything about what's running on the client - if it's a custom app then you could potentially find out the IMEI in the app and include it in the data. Of course, any program can send any data, so you'd possibly want some way of signing or encrypting the IMEI so you knew you could trust it at the server side...

Comment: No, i know. But i seek a generic string field to pass data with this class.

Comment: @petre: It's really not clear what you're after then. Where are you expecting the IMEI to come from? What's connecting to the server? (See my edit which *may* help, but if it doesn't you'll need to make your question much clearer.)

Comment: I am actually expecting a string data in NewClient class and this data obviously comes from a client.

Comment: @petre: "a client" is pretty vague. It could be a web browser, or some custom component in a phone which you can't control. Basically if my current answer doesn't help you, your question is too vague to answer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints